# Issue with coefficient estimate in linear trend regression model with autocorrelation of residuals

Tags: regression, residuals, autocorrelation, autoregressive, trend

The question is simple, generally the coefficient estimate is not affected by autocorrelation of residuals when the independent and dependent variable are distinct. I am not sure about the clear distinction in the case of linear trend model such as

```
y = alpha + beta*t
```

Looking at it specially the y and t term seem to be distinct. So my query is as stated in the title, will the coefficient estimate be affected or not. If so, some explanation on that would be helpful!

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct"?

Comment: Basically a cross sectional regression, what ends up happening sometimes is the independent variable is a actually a lag of the dependent variable and the regression coefficients are estimated. In this case where the independent is a lag of the dependent you would say the independent and the dependent variable aren't distinct

Comment: Οk. Then the next question is:  which estimation method/estimator do you have in mind?